# React update content of a script tag

Tags: reactjs, script-tag

I have the following script tag:

```
<script>
window.ac_vh_params = {
    containerId: 'container',
    folderName: '33/334'
};
</script>
<script src="https://somesdomain/main.js"></script>
```

My goal is to update and reload this script depend on a specific value, so I did the following:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Demo = () => {
  const [selectedFolderName, setSelectedFolderName] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedFolderName) {
      return;
    }
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
    container.innerHTML = '';
    const script1 = document.createElement('script');
    script1.text = `window.ac_vh_params = { containerId: 'container', folderName: '${selectedFolderName}' };`;
    container.appendChild(script1);
    const script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.src = 'https://somesdomain/main.js';
    container.appendChild(script2);
    return () => {
      container.removeChild(script1);
      container.removeChild(script2);
    }
  }, [selectedFolderName]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.getAttribute('name') || e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name');
    setSelectedFolderName(name);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <button name="button1" onClick={handleClick}>Click 1</button>
      <button name="button2" onClick={handleClick}>Click 2</button>
      <div className="container">
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

The code changes as expected, but the new code not reloaded. How can I solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the parameters in the UseEffect itself? Something like

```
useEffect(()=>{

if (selectedFolderName) {
   window.ac_vh_params = { containerId: 'container', folderName: '${selectedFolderName}' };
    }
}
//... rest of code
)
```

Comment: Yes, it's not working. I need to update Iframe and to reload it, I guess, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by the following code:

```
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].contentWindow.document;
// const doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
container.open();
container.write(`
<script>
    window.ac_vh_params = {
        containerId: 'container',
        folderName: '${selectedFolderName}'
    };
</script>
<script src="https://somedomain/main.js"></script>
`);
container.close();
```